# Principal Component Analysis - first component product normalised to $1$

Tags: matrices, statistics

I am using $Matlab$ to run the $PCA$ of a set of data variables that I have.

I have a $80 \times 13$ matrix, and have taken the first principal component using the following code:

> My question is this: Is the transpose of the first principal component times the the first principal component meant to equal $1$?

i.e. $P'P = 1$ ?

In my case it doesn't, how can I achieve it if this is required?

Many thanks,
Kind regards,

KB

MATLAB CODE:

%% Basic

clc 
clear all

%% Load Data - my 80 x 13 data series matrix

filename = 'DataFinal.xlsx';
A = xlsread(filename);

% Principal Component Analysis

[n m] = size(A); %size of A

%We can use the Zscore function, to demean and divide by the
%standard deviation

BB = zscore(A);

%Calculating the coefficients of princ components and respective variances
%, done by finding eigenfunctions of sample covariance matrix

[V D] = eig(cov(B))

% V here contains the coefficients of principal components, diagonal
% elements of D store the variance of respective principal components.

%Alternatively the below is a better way of calculating our principal
%components and their variance.

[COEFF SCORE LATENT] = princomp(B)

%COEFF is a 13x13 square matrix
%LATENT is 13x1  matrix
%SCORE is 80x13 matrix (same dimensions as original time series set)

% Cumulative variance contained in first so many principal components can
% be calculated as:

cumsum(var(SCORE)) / sum(var(SCORE))

% Also note all of the principal components are completely uncorrelated

Comment: Edit: this is my MATLAB code thus far. What I would like to impose is the restriction that the first principal component, when multiplied by its transpose, equals the scalar 1.